# get list of opened Excel documents in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here i get Word document opened file list successfully..

```
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordObj;
            WordObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

                x = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < WordObj.Windows.Count; i++)
                {
                    object idx = i + 1;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window WinObj = WordObj.Windows.get_Item(ref idx);

                    // doc_list.Add(WinObj.Document.FullName);


                    x = x + "," + WinObj.Document.FullName;

                    //x = WinObj.Document.FullName;
                }                                                         

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            // No documents opened
        }
```

As same as i wantt to get Excel files list...

```
        try
        {
             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj;
             ExcelObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
             //excel = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
                x = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < ExcelObj.Windows.Count; i++)
                {
                    object idx = i + 1;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window WinObj = ExcelObj.Windows.get_Item(idx);

                    doc_list.Add(WinObj.Document.FullName);

                  //Here is the problem ,How can i get FullName of opened excel file

                  // x = x + "," + WinObj.Activate.

                  //  x = WinObj.Document.FullName;
                }                  
        }   
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Excel file not getting..This Line..
In every word document getting fine..with WinObj.Document.Fullname but 
In Excel **x = x + "," + WinObj.Document.FullName;** No Propertity for Excel File name Document...How Can i get File Full name as same as word..

Comment: Every time you empty-catch an exception, a kitten dies.

Comment: Note that the model changes between Excel 2010 to 2013 (ish) - which are you targetting?

Comment: I am using Excel 2010..I want to display opened excel opened document file names..Is it possible to find this way..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on stackoverflow

You can try it.

```
//Excel Application Object
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcelApp;

this.Activate ( );

//Get reference to Excel.Application from the ROT.
oExcelApp = ( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject ( "Excel.Application" );

//Display the name of the object.
MessageBox.Show ( oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.FullName );

//Release the reference.
oExcelApp = null;
```

I found this here
[How to get the current open documents in Excel using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449387/how-to-get-the-current-open-documents-in-excel-using-c)

and here

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/316126

Comment: It's Working fine...Thank you...Kevinkrs , Can you give me suggition for Power point Applicatin as same as same requirement...?is it possible to Get the instance of the PPT file...?